# Unable to send the Emails from the R

Tags: r, sendmail, sendmailr

Am unable to send the email through the R, even after less secure apps access allowed (ON).

```
library(xtable)
library(mailR)
library(sendmailR)
library(rJava)  

send.mail(from = "eduru.suresh@swiggy.in",
to = c("suresh.eduru1@gmail.com"),
subject= paste0("Report 1 : Raipur City Performance Metrics"),
body=print(xtable(Raipur,caption = "Raipur City Performance Metrics"),
type="html", caption.placement = "top"),
html = TRUE,
smtp = list(host.name="smtp.gmail.com",port=465,
user.name="xxxxxx@xxxx.in",
passwd="xxxxxxx",ssl=TRUE),
authenticate = TRUE,
send = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is there any error message and/or output from the above call to `send.mail`?  Your settings look correct for Gmail.

Comment: Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465;org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
 at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
 at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Sour